# xargs formation with ipinfo.io to get info in one line

Tags: linux, api, geolocation, xargs

The http://ipinfo.io getting started example for specific info tag like so:

```
cat ips.txt | xargs -I% curl -s http://ipinfo.io/%/org | paste -d"," ips.txt -
```

Return:

```
8.8.8.8,AS15169 Google Inc.
8.8.4.4,AS15169 Google Inc.
1.2.3.4,AS15169 Google Inc.
```

I want multiple pieces of info so I changed there example to:

```
cat ips.txt | xargs -I% curl -s http://ipinfo.io/%/city http://ipinfo.io/%/region | paste -d"," ips.txt - > ip_info.txt
```

Return:

```
156.221.17.167,Punjab
,Dol pri Ljubljani
```

how can I format my request to fit all the info relate to the IP in same line separated by a comma ',' like so:

```
156.221.17.167,Punjab,Dol pri Ljubljani
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple pieces of information you're better off getting it all in a single request and then using `jq` to pull out the pieces you want. Here's the full JSON output for an IP (see http://ipinfo.io/developers for more examples):

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8
{
  "ip": "8.8.8.8",
  "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.3860,-122.0838",
  "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
  "postal": "94035"
}
```

Then using jq to pull out the IP, city and country into CSV:

```
$ curl -s ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8 | jq -r '[.ip, .city, .country] | @csv'
"8.8.8.8","Mountain View","US"
```

If we have a file with a bunch of IPs we can do it like this:

```
$ cat ips.txt | xargs -I% curl -s http://ipinfo.io/%/json | jq -r '[.ip, .city, .country] | @csv'
```